# What does it mean to inflating a view from an xml file?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hey I'm new to android can someone please explain me What does it mean to inflate a view from an xml file in little detail.

As I'm trying to show some data on RecyclerView from an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects. It is never used directly. Instead, use `getLayoutInflater()` or `getSystemService(Class)` to retrieve a standard LayoutInflater instance that is already hooked up to the current context and correctly configured for the device you are running on. For example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

[official documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)